# Is there a browser add-on that imposes a cooldown period for websites?

Tags: browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I'd like to prevent myself from opening a given site (e.g. facebook.com) too soon after the last time it was opened. Is there a browser add-on (ideally - for Firefox) that does that? Or I should write it myself...

Answer (score 2):

There is an addon called [Leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/leechblock/):

> LeechBlock is a simple productivity tool designed to block those
>   time-wasting sites that can suck the life out of your working day. All
>   you need to do is specify which sites to block and when to block them.